# Inno Setup Repair button

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Have some question. I'm working with Inno Setup and I need to add Change and Repair button to Windows Programs and Features panel. 
The Change button was added by using AppModifyPath directive in [Setup] part.
So, how i can to do something same and add Repair button ??

Comment: The `AppModifyPath` toggles between creating `NoModify=1` and `ModifyPath=%AppModifyPath%` registry entries. While the `NoRepair=1` is created always. Interestingly removing `NoRepair` does not help and there does not seem to be a `ModifyPath` equivalent for "Repair". The MSI installers that have the *"Repair"* button indeed do not have the `NoRepair=1` value and adding one to them removes their button. But I didn't really find what defines what the "Repair" button does.

Comment: Consider asking non-Inno Setup specific question with generic "windows" and "installer" tags.

Comment: Related: `Move` and the linked text: `Advanced Options` in W10 Apps & Features.